# npm run dev Error:The number of constructor arguments in the derived class t must be >= than the number of constructor arguments of its base class

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I am using vue with Laravel5.8 in vagrant when I run npm run development I get below error.

root@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant/webroot# npm run development

```
> @ development /vagrant/webroot
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

91% additional asset processing                                                        
/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/planner.js:107
            throw new Error(error.message);
                  ^
Error: The number of constructor arguments in the derived class t must be >= than the number of constructor arguments of its base class.
    at _createSubRequests (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/planner.js:107:19)
    at Object.plan (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/planner.js:126:5)
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/container.js:239:37
    at Container._get (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/container.js:232:44)
    at Container.get (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/container.js:191:21)
    at e.value (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/node_modules/javascript-obfuscator/dist/webpack:/src/container/InversifyContainerFacade.ts:121:34)
    at Function.value (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/node_modules/javascript-obfuscator/dist/webpack:/src/JavaScriptObfuscator.ts:26:17)
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/index.js:44:66
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack-obfuscator/index.js:22:23)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:669:10

    at next (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)

at Compilation.<anonymous> (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js:115:6)
    at next (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:275:11)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:665:9
    at next (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js:111:6)
    at next (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:244:13
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at iteratorCallback (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1064:13)
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:227:15
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at iteratorCallback (/vagrant/webroot/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1064:13)
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
    at /vagrant/webroot/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:216:21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-10T12_47_07_496Z-debug.log
```

I am using below

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "dropzone": "^4.3.0",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "echarts": "^3.7.1",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.14",
    "highcharts-more": "^0.1.2",
    "javascript-obfuscator": "^0.27.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "opencollective": "^1.0.3",
    "postinstall": "^0.7.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.3",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "tether": "^1.4.0",
    "tinycon": "github:tommoor/tinycon",
    "video.js": "^5.20.3",
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "vue-loader": "^11.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.0.1",
    "vuex": "^2.4.0",
    "webpack-obfuscator": "^0.10.2"
  }
}
```

Please help, I have tried multiple times by deleting node_modules folder and package-lock.json but still getting same error.

node version : v14.16.0

npm version : 6.14.11

Answer (score 0):

Is something that we added to ensure that a developer won't forget to pass some arguments to the super constructor. We did this to prevent people from wasting time trying to figure out why some injection was missing. By default, it forces both the derived and super constructors to match but that is just the default behavior.

We implemented a decorator named @unmanaged() to allow your use case. In your derived constructor, you are injecting something into the base class via its super constructor. It is important to understand that is injection is done by your code and not by the IoC container. For this reason, we consider this an "unmanaged" injection since the injection is not managed by inversify:

On your derived class construct argument put that decorator

@unmanaged().

Gonna be something like

see that link: https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/522

Answer (score -1):

in my case just disable JavaScriptObfuscator in webpack prod then its start working modules is ok just maybe somwher error when, then manual obfuscate some js files

```
//new JavaScriptObfuscator ({
//     rotateUnicodeArray: true
//   }, ['excluded_bundle_name.js']
// ),
```